# Nautilus shortcut initially does not work for SSD

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, ssd, shortcuts

I have built a new computer with two M.2 PCIe 4.0 SSD drives on the motherboard, one of which contains the operating system (Ubuntu 20.04), the other which is used for data.  I created a shortcut in Nautilus to the SSD which contains data.  When I boot the machine and click on the shortcut, I get an error "Oops! Something went wrong.  Unable to find the requested file.  Please check the spelling and try again." (See attached png).  If I click on Other Locations in Nautilus and then click on the SSD drive, it immediately works and thereafter the shortcut will work until the next reboot.  It's a minor problem, but does anyone have a clue how I could resolve this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default, except for the root partition and eventually a separate home partition, partitions are only mounted "on demand" in linux. That happens when you click the icon of the partition in Files.

You can have a drive mount automatically during start up, such that indeed links immediately work after the system is ready. The classical way to achieve that is to manually edit the configuration file `/etc/fstab`: a line is added giving instructions to the system about where and how to mount the drive. Nowadays, you can achieve that using utility "Disks".

- In the left pane, highlight the drive
- On the map, click the partition you want to automount
- Click the cog wheel and select "Edit mount options".
  On the form, you need to provide the Mount Point. That is an empty folder where you want the contents of the drive to appear after mounting. You also need to indicate the "Filesystem Type". You can see the file system when you clicked the partition in the map, but you will need to "translate" to the linux symbol (e.g. `ext4` instead of "Ext4", `vfat` rather than "FAT (32-bit version)".